# why should I remove 'a' here?

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

A native English speaker has revised my writing. He changed

> This has been added as a future work.

to

> This has been added as future work.

I wonder, why I should remove `a` ?

Comment: _A work_ usually refers to a work of art. Most of the time we use _work_ in a non-countable way. That is, just _work_ and not _a work_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Work** has many definitions.  From [dictionary.com's definition of *work*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/work?s=t):

> This has been added as future work.

1. exertion or effort directed to produce or accomplish something; labor; toil.
2. productive or operative activity.
3. employment, as in some form of industry, especially as a means of earning one's livelihood: to look for work.
4. one's place of employment:  Don't phone him at work.

These usages of *work* don't take an article, typically.  *Painting a fence is a lot of work*, e.g., or *Harry doesn't like work very much.*

> This has been added as a future work.

This would be correct with this definition:

5. something on which exertion or labor is expended; a task or undertaking:
   The students finished their work in class.
6. materials, things, etc., on which one is working or is to work.
   7  the result of exertion, labor, or activity; a deed or performance.

For example:  *My favourite Shakespeare play is a work of incredible talent.*

Thus, your proposed correction may or not be correct, depending on your context.